# A question about class equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$  is a group, then class equation is given by

$$|G|=|Z(G)|+ \sum_{i=1}^K[G:C_{G}(x_i)] $$

where $x_i\notin Z(G)$

For dihedral group $D_8$, class equation is given by

$$2+2+2+2$$

but there is another way to write this is

$$1+1+2+2+2$$

My question is: why here two representaions for center of a group is? If order of  center is 3( or >3), then is it possible to write  as $1+2 $ ? please someone help.Thanks

Comment: While it is of course also true that $8=1+3+4$ or $8=\frac12(5^2-3^2)$, those truths wouldn't really represent the class equation

Answer (score 2):

The class equation 
$$|G|=|Z(G)|+ \sum_{i=1}^K[G:C_{G}(x_i)] $$, $x_i$ is not in the center.  Now
$|Z(G)|$ is in fact the sum of order of singleton equivalence classes if we go back to the definitions of the defining equivalence relation.

Comment: Adelafif:yes,you are write.you mean there are only two possibility to write center .